# @Update on specific field on RoomDB Android not updated properly

Tags: android, sql, android-room

@Update on specific field on RoomDB Android not updated properly

When insert it work properly
[image]

When call logger.updateLog(key, msg) the room db didn't update
Should I use common @query instead?
[image]
Using db inspector
[image]

In Dao Class

```
@Dao
interface LogDao {

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun updateLog(obj: Log)

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(vararg logs: Log)
```

In impl class

```
override fun addLog(key: String, msg: String) {
        executorService.execute {
            logDao.insert(
                Log(
                    msg,
                    key,
                    System.currentTimeMillis()
                )
            )
        }
    }

    override fun updateLog(key: String, msg: String) {
        executorService.execute {
            logDao.updateLog(
                Log(
                    msg,
                    key,
                    System.currentTimeMillis()
                )
            )
        }
    }
```

In presenter

```
fun saveRecord(
        key: String,
        msg: String
    ) {
        logger.isContainKey(key) {
            if (it) {
                logger.updateLog(key, msg)
            } else
                logger.addLog(key, msg)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case just want to update if the field key is the same

This code work fine for me

```
@Query("UPDATE logs SET timestamp = :timestamp, msg = :msg WHERE `key` = :key")
fun forceUpdate(msg: String,key: String,timestamp:Long)

fun updateLog(log:Log){
    forceUpdate(log.msg,log.key,log.timestamp)
}
```